# Finding minimum depth of BST ... findHeight function won't work

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, depth

Trying to solve this LC Easy: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/

Which is to find the minimum depth (number of nodes on shortest path) of a tree.

I was able to create a "findheight" function which gives me the height of a tree.

My logic was to use findheight to find the height of both subtrees (left and right) of a root node, and then return the minimum between the two heights.

```
class Solution {
    public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null){return 0;}
        int left = findHeight(root.left);
        int right = findHeight(root.right);

        //unbalanced tree, only one subtree 
        if(left == 0 || right == 0){
            return Math.max(left,right) + 1;
        }
        return Math.min(left,right) + 1 ;
    }
    
    public int findHeight(TreeNode root){
        if(root == null){return 0;}
        int left = findHeight(root.left);
        int right = findHeight(root.right);
        return Math.max(left,right) + 1;
    }
}
```

It won't pass the test case:

[-9,-3,2,null,4,4,0,-6,null,-5]

Or:

[image]

```
Output:
4
Expected:
3
```

My thought process right now is that when I use "findHeight", I'm returning back the 'max' height per left and right subtree. In this test case, I should be returning back the minimum height.

I changed my code to "Math.min" in another iteration, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas or theories why? So confused!! Should I just abandon this approach altogether?

Comment: Describe your code, the problem and what you want to achieve directly into your post, instead of referencing to an external link

Comment: Sorry, I am new to StackOverflow. I have edited my question to explain my thought process more.

Comment: @buddybuddybuddybuddy,  `findHeight` currently finds the maximum height. i have added a working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue in current code

```
//unbalanced tree, only one subtree 
if(left == 0 || right == 0){
  return Math.max(left,right) + 1;
}
```

The above lines of code checks the imbalance only at `root level`. It does not recursively check imbalance at lower levels.

### Check imbalance at every level

```java
    public int minDepth(final TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        final int left = minDepth(node.left);
        final int right = minDepth(node.right);
        
        // if both paths exist, then return the minimum
        if (node.left != null && node.right != null) {
            return Math.min(left, right) + 1;
        } else {
            // if zero or one path exists return that path (so take maximum)
            return Math.max(left, right) + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your well commented code, I will explore and experiment with your solution!